# Finding solution to this inequality algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x + 3^x < 4$$

My attempted incorrect solution:

$$3^x < 4 - x$$
$$3 \log(x) < \log(4 - x)$$
$$10^3x < 4 - x$$
$$10^3x + x < 4$$
$$x(10^3 + 1) < 4$$
$$x < 4/(10^3+1)$$

However I know the solution set to this inequality is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x < 1\}$. Where am I making my mistake? This problem is from the Spivak, Calculus textbook pg. 14 problem 4.12.

Comment: Your first line after taking logs should read $x \log 3$ not $3 \log x$.

Comment: You won't solve this inequality analytically.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the function $f(x) = x+3^x$ is increasing thus if $x < 1\to f(x) < f(1) = 4$,and this gives the solutions: $(-\infty,1)$